# c# white, can't find element at window

Tags: c#, white-framework

Sorry for disturbance but it seems that I need your help.
I am really beginner in C#, White framework.

Here is the problem...
I am trying to automate WinForm application, very basic.

Manual steps for automation:

1. Open window
2. Download file to this window
3. Find caption at bottom of this window

Problem: I can press any buttons, open dialogs and so on.
But after several steps I can't find label (caption).

I tried this code at 2 PCs. For one PC it works, for other - doesn't work.
I saw only one time that this label was found.

Usually I see that Studio just hang up and trying to search elements.

I think that Studio works very quickly and elements are not available for reading. Could you help me with this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwECD.jpg)

```
        //Add file name for opening
        TextBox listLoadFile = mainWindow.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByText("File name:"));
        listLoadFile.Text = "Omneon_72.lst";
        application.WaitWhileBusy();

        //  open file
        Keyboard.Instance.PressSpecialKey(KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.RETURN);
        application.WaitWhileBusy();

        mainWindow.Focus();
        mainWindow.ReloadIfCached();

        //Can't find this element
        Label caption3 = mainWindow.Get<Label>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("lblStatus"));

        //Can't see elements
        IUIItem[] children1 = mainWindow.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.All);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of reloading `mainWindow` you'd just reattach the process again.

```
    process = Process.GetProcessesByName("myProcess")[0];
    application = Application.Attach(process.Id);
    mainWindow = application.GetWindow("myWindowTitle");

    Label caption3 = mainWindow.Get<Label>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("lblStatus"));
    IUIItem[] children1 = mainWindow.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.All);
```